# Isn't this code snippet for checking digits supposed to return false?

Tags: javascript

This is to check only digits in a string.. It's returning true when I expected to return me a false..
How can I fix this and why it's returning me a true?

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      function test()
var str2 ="s123s";
var reg3 =/\d/;
alert(reg3.test(str2));
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You regex is testing **if there is one digit in the string** -- and not if the string contains only digits.

If you what to check for a string that

- starts with a digit,
- contains one or more digits -- and nothing else,
- and end with a digit,

you should change your regex to something like this :

```
/^\d+$/
```

Comment: humph, true ^^ -- even though the regex is OK ; I'll edit my answer to make the second point more clear :-)

Answer (score 2):

Your regexp `\d` checks if there is a digit. Use `\D` to check if there is a non-digit and return the negation of that test.

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression is "Contains a number", so it should alert `true`.

If you wanted "Contains nothing but numbers" then you would want:

```
/^\d*$/   /* Start of string, zero or more numbers, end of string */
```

Or:

```
!/\D/.test(str2)   /* Test for presence of non-numbers, then NOT the result */
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually if you want it to contain nothing but numbers this is the correct one:

```
/^\d+$/
```

The following will allow empty string too:

```
/^\d*$/
```